# Google Analytics Experiment -- How to test shopping cart

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

We have:
    GET landing.html (then select a production)
    POST cart1.php (then select options)
    POST cart2.php (then enter billing info)
    POST cart3.php (will process payment and then redirect
    GET  thankyou.html

I want to run an experiment on cart2.php to increase conversions.

How do I do this in Google Analytics?

UPDATE:

If I do the basic tracking, I lose the transaction details. For example, here is:

- A simple form (that leads into a shopping cart)
- An original shopping cart page 1
- An experimental shopping cart page 1

[image]

[image]

[image]

====================

This is an example of the cart that will not work with Analytics:

=== 1.php ===

```
<form action="2.php" method="get">
<input name="name">
<button>GO</button>
</form>
```

=== 2.php ===

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code SNIP -->
<!-- Google Analytics Tracking code SNIP -->
</head>
<body>
<p>2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

=== 2b.php ===

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- Google Analytics Tracking code SNIP -->
</head>
<body>
<p>2b</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Google Analytics account and implement the code on your website. Then cross-check that it's tracking your site correctly. If done right, head over to "Experiments":

[image: Google Content Experiments]

Enter the URL of the page you'd like to run your test on:

[image]

After which you are presented with this:

[image]

Now you simply add another variant of your cart2.php page there and let Google Analytics figure out which does better ... That is all.

Comment: But wont I lose all the data that the user POSTed into the form?

Comment: actually i do not understand what you mean? your variation page needs to of course work just like your default page would... testing is done through google dividing up traffic between both variants and then measuring conversion on your next step (cart3.php).  so if 100 visitors see cart2 and 100 see cart2variation but only 3 go on to cart3 from cart2 and 8 go to cart3 from cart2variation, that variation wins ...

Comment: This is not working, I have updated the question with details

Comment: This IS working. Exactly, what is it that you are trying to A/B test then?

Comment: The problem is that when the user loads the original /del/2.php page, the shopping cart has all the products they chose during checkout. However, when (and if) Google Analytics sends them to the /del/2b.php page they see an empty shopping cart.

Comment: Seems to me this is not directly related to the experiment setup, but that your variations page does not work with your ecommerce setup. what shopping cart system do you use? self-baked, woocommerce, magento, ...?

Comment: This is a self-baked cart. Very often carts are based on POST requests and will fail the same way. I have pasted the minimized example that illustrates the problem.